# Remove file with write group permission

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, rm

I'm using Raspbian Stretch Lite and I followed an official [tutorial from RapberryPi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ftp.md) to set up Pure-FTPd. So now I have a virtual user that can create files through FTP owned by `ftpuser:ftpgroup`. 
I also add `pi` user in `ftpgroup` with following command :

```
usermod -a -G ftpgroup pi
```

But when I try to delete a file created by `ftpuser` it says

> Operation not permitted

Here is a copy of my console :

```
pi@raspberry(rw):/var/ftp$ ls -la
total 4
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root       60 Jun 20 15:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root    root     4096 May  7 17:04 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ftpuser ftpgroup 0 Jun 20 16:03 test
pi@raspberry(rw):/var/ftp$ whoami
pi
pi@raspberry(rw):/var/ftp$ grep -i --color 'ftpgroup' /etc/group
ftpgroup:x:1001:pi
pi@raspberry(rw):/var/ftp$ rm test
rm: cannot remove 'test': Operation not permitted
```

I don't understand why I can't remove *test* file if I'm in the ftpgroup and group has write permission.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need write permissions om the directory as well. You change the TOC.

To illustrate this:

```
[ronald@lion tmp]$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root    19 Jun 20 15:48 .
drwx------. 6 ronald ronald 195 Jun 20 15:48 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 ronald ronald   0 Jun 20 15:48 hallo
[ronald@lion tmp]$ rm hallo
rm: cannot remove ‘hallo’: Permission denied
[ronald@lion tmp]$ id
uid=1000(ronald) gid=1000(ronald) groups=1000(ronald) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[ronald@lion tmp]$ su
Password: 
[root@lion tmp]# chmod 777 .
[root@lion tmp]# exit
[ronald@lion tmp]$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root   root    19 Jun 20 15:48 .
drwx------. 6 ronald ronald 195 Jun 20 15:48 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 ronald ronald   0 Jun 20 15:48 hallo
[ronald@lion tmp]$ rm hallo
[ronald@lion tmp]$
```

Comment: It seems that I already have write permission on parent directory `drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root       60 Jun 20 15:58 .`

Comment: But directory is created at boot from `/etc/fstab` with the following line `tmpfs /var/ftp tmpfs nodev,nosuid,size=512M 0 0`. Am I doing something wrong for permissions?

Comment: Fixed with that `tmpfs /var/ftp tmpfs nodev,nosuid,size=512M,mode=0777 0 0`! It seems that _drwxrwxrwt_ was not ok...

Comment: It was the sticky bit that prevented you from removing the file. (the "t"). At least the man page of chmod states: "For directories, it prevents unprivileged users from moving or renaming a  file  in  the directory  unless they own the file or the directory".

Answer (score -2):

You need write permissions with sudo usermod -a -G ftpgroup pi or you can can add pi user to sudo group with visudo, its work for me you please try once and let me know.